# How can I get subgroups of the match in Scala?

Tags: python, scala, grouping

I have the following in python:

```
  regex.sub(lambda t: t.group(1).replace(" ", "  ") + t.group(2),string)
```

where `regex` is a Regular Expression and `string` is a filled String.

So I am trying to do the same in Scala, using `regex.replaceAllIn(...)` function instead of python`sub`. However, I don't know how to get the subgroups that match.

Is there something similar to python function `group` in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaladoc has one example. Provide a function from `Match` instead of a string.

```
scala> val r = "a(b)(c)+".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = a(b)(c)+

scala> val s = "123 abcccc and abcc"
s: String = 123 abcccc and abcc

scala> r.replaceAllIn(s, m => s"a${m.group(1).toUpperCase}${m.group(2)*3}")
res0: String = 123 aBccc and aBccc
```

The resulting string also does group substitution.

```
scala> val r = "a(b)(c+)".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = a(b)(c+)

scala> r.replaceAllIn(s, m => if (m.group(2).length > 3) "$1" else "$2")
res3: String = 123 b and cc

scala> r.replaceAllIn(s, m => s"$$${ if (m.group(2).length > 3) 1 else 2 }")
res4: String = 123 b and cc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceAll`, and use `$n`, where "n" is the group you want to match. For example:

```
yourString.replaceAll(yourRegex, "$1")
```

Replaces the matched parts with the first group.

Comment: With the case example, you could get a new String capturing all groups isn't? Like in my example. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe other way to do this is having a `regex`, for example:

```
val regExtractor = """a(b+)(c+)(d*)""".r
```

And then match the `String:`

```
val string = "abbbbbbbbbccdd"

val newString = string match {
  case regExtractor(g1, g2, g3) =>
    s"""String Replaced: ${g1.replace(g1, "XXXXX")},
        | ${g2.replace(g2, "YYYYY")}""".stripMargin
}
```

`newString` will be:

```
"String Replaced: XXXXX, YYYYY"
```